# Excel 2007 Sum, if, and not working

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

The following formula worked in a previous version of excel but in 2007 returns a value #name?
In cell J17 I have the formula

`=IF(H16=""I""I(SUM(H10-H16+2)+SUM(IF(AND(K4<=18IK4>=H11)I1I0))+SUM(IF(AND(K4>18IK4-18>=H11)I1I0))+SUM(IF(AND(K4>18)I1I0))))`

The values of cells H10 and K4 are numbers and H16 if not a number should return a blank ic cell J17 but if a number should compute the results of the remaining logical answers.

Comment: hi Lloyd, have you tried simplifying the formula (in a copy) to find out in which part of it the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this section...

> `=IF(H16=""I""I(SUM(H10-...`

This:

**""I""I**

... (I = upper case i) is unlikely to be anything viable.

It appears in a place where a function name could be appropriate, which is likely to be the cause for displaying "#name"

Type `=mama()` (a call to a non-existant function) in an empty cell and you will see the same.

I also see uppercase I in other places, where it is unlikely to be correct.  At least two of those places should likely have a `,`or a `;` instead - depending on your locale settings.

---

Pondering on the content, it seems you have "i" all over the place, replacing those with "," converts it to this:

> =IF(H16="","",(SUM(H10-H16+2)+SUM(IF(AND(K4<=18,K4>=H11),1,0))+SUM(IF(AND(K4>18,K4-18>=H11),1,0))+SUM(IF(AND(K4>18),1,0))))

... which makes more sense.

Even more sense; remove the SUM()'s they make no difference. So:

> =IF(H16="","",(H10-H16+2+IF(AND(K4<=18,K4>=H11),1,0)+IF(AND(K4>18,K4-18>=H11),1,0)+IF(AND(K4>18),1,0)))

With that in A1 and nothing else in the worksheet, you get no errors, and and empty cell - as it should be according to the formula.

Try it out with your data (in the cells mentioned in the formula).

Comment: Thank you Ruud The capital i was used in the original formula instead of , I have tried to replace with , and get a formula error same goes for ;  If I copy the original formula across it works even when I replace the values of the cell but bombs out if I click on or change the formula parameters.

Comment: Strange... just to make sure you get what is intended; run Notepad.exe, copy & paste the formula into Notepad, then COPY it AGAIN (YES!) from notepad to where you want it. This operation is to ensure that there is NO other info included than the formula text itself.

Comment: Added new stuff above. BTW; Not ruud.

Comment: Hi Hannu (apologies for the wrong name previously) Thank you for your input and assistance. I tried your example with , iso I no luck does not recognse it as a formula no matter how I type or paste it. I am convinced that there is a bug or corruption in my version of excel. Due to lock-down regulations I cannot at present get to my install disc, which is at my holiday home.

Comment: Download and install e.g. LibreOffice, it works VERY much the same as Excel.